# RadioButton and CheckBox Automatically Display After Clicked

Tags: android-studio, mobile, checkbox, radio-button

Hello I am making a order page for individual items on the menu.

My problem is when I click a RadioButton and CheckBox the price does not show. I have to press the quantity button for it to appear.

Also when I press another RadioButton and CheckBox it stays from the previous price. And wilw only change when I press the quanitiy button again.

Here is the Java Code RadioButton:

```
    plusquantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int radioID = radioG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if(radioID == R.id.hotradioButton){
                int basePrice = 100;
                quantity++;
                displayQuantity();
                int coffePrice = basePrice * quantity;
                String setnewPrice = String.valueOf(coffePrice);
                coffeePrice.setText(setnewPrice);

                int ifCheckBox = CalculatePrice(addCream1, addSyrup, addNata,addJelly);
                coffeePrice.setText("P " + ifCheckBox);


            }else if(radioID == R.id.coldRadioButton){

                int basePrice = 140;
                quantity++;
                displayQuantity();
                int coffePrice = basePrice * quantity;
                String setnewPrice = String.valueOf(coffePrice);
                coffeePrice.setText(setnewPrice);

                int ifCheckBox = CalculatePrice2(addCream1, addSyrup, addNata,addJelly);
                coffeePrice.setText("P " + ifCheckBox);

            }else if(radioID == R.id.blendRadioButton){

                int basePrice = 150;
                quantity++;
                displayQuantity();
                int coffePrice = basePrice * quantity;
                String setnewPrice = String.valueOf(coffePrice);
                coffeePrice.setText(setnewPrice);

                int ifCheckBox = CalculatePrice3(addCream1, addSyrup, addNata,addJelly);
                coffeePrice.setText("P " + ifCheckBox);

            }


        }
        private void displayQuantity() {
            quantitynumber.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
        }

    });

    
    minusquantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int radioID = radioG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if (radioID == R.id.hotradioButton) {
                int basePrice = 100;

                if (quantity == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(Espresso_Item1.this, "Cannot Decrease Quantity", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    quantity--;
                    displayQuantity();
                    int coffePrice = basePrice * quantity;
                    String setnewPrice = String.valueOf(coffePrice);
                    coffeePrice.setText(setnewPrice);

                    int ifCheckBox = CalculatePrice(addCream1, addSyrup, addNata,addJelly);
                    coffeePrice.setText("P " + ifCheckBox);



                }
            }else if (radioID == R.id.coldRadioButton){
                int basePrice = 140;


                if (quantity == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(Espresso_Item1.this, "Cannot Decrease Quantity", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    quantity--;
                    displayQuantity();
                    int coffePrice = basePrice * quantity;
                    String setnewPrice = String.valueOf(coffePrice);
                    coffeePrice.setText(setnewPrice);

                    int ifCheckBox = CalculatePrice2(addCream1, addSyrup, addNata,addJelly);
                    coffeePrice.setText("P " + ifCheckBox);


                }

            }else if(radioID == R.id.blendRadioButton){
                int basePrice = 150;


                if (quantity == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(Espresso_Item1.this, "Cannot Decrease Quantity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    quantity--;
                    displayQuantity();
                    int coffePrice = basePrice * quantity;
                    String setnewPrice = String.valueOf(coffePrice);
                    coffeePrice.setText(setnewPrice);

                    int ifCheckBox = CalculatePrice3(addCream1, addSyrup, addNata,addJelly);
                    coffeePrice.setText("P " + ifCheckBox);


                }

            }
        }

        private void displayQuantity() {
            quantitynumber.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
        }
    });

}
```

CheckBox Java Code:

```
  private int CalculatePrice3(CheckBox addCream1, CheckBox addSyrup, CheckBox addNata, 
  CheckBox addJelly) {
    int basePrice = 150;

    if (addCream1.isChecked()) {

        basePrice = basePrice + 20;
    }

    if (addSyrup.isChecked()) {

        basePrice = basePrice + 20;
    }

    if (addNata.isChecked()) {

        basePrice = basePrice + 20;
    }
    if (addJelly.isChecked()) {

        basePrice = basePrice + 20;
    }

    return basePrice * quantity;
}

    private int CalculatePrice2(CheckBox addCream1, CheckBox addSyrup, CheckBox addNata, 
  CheckBox addJelly) {
    int basePrice = 140;

    if (addCream1.isChecked()) {

        basePrice = basePrice + 20;
    }

    if (addSyrup.isChecked()) {

        basePrice = basePrice + 20;
    }

    if (addNata.isChecked()) {

        basePrice = basePrice + 20;
    }
    if (addJelly.isChecked()) {

        basePrice = basePrice + 20;
    }

    return basePrice * quantity;
   }

  private int CalculatePrice(CheckBox addCream, CheckBox addSyrup, CheckBox addNata, CheckBox 
  addJelly) {

    int basePrice = 100;

    if (addCream1.isChecked()) {

        basePrice = basePrice + 20;
    }

    if (addSyrup.isChecked()) {

        basePrice = basePrice + 20;
    }

    if (addNata.isChecked()) {

        basePrice = basePrice + 20;
    }
    if (addJelly.isChecked()) {

        basePrice = basePrice + 20;
    }

    return basePrice * quantity;
}

private void displayQuantity() {
    quantitynumber.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
}
```

Here is the design of the page for a visual reference: https://postimg.cc/YvWtnwCK

Any help is appreicated!

Comment: It appears that you've already asked a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73343749/automatically-display-values-after-radio-button-clicked) and I responded to that answer.

Comment: @shagberg I'm sorry I still don't understand how it works.

Comment: @shagberg is it alright to have a further explanation. If it's alright with you. Much appreciated

Comment: I tried to explain it as clearly as I could in the other Stackoverflow question. The reason that the price doesn't appear right away is because you have the code to show the price within the plusquantity.setOnClickListener. The code within setOnClickListener WILL ONLY RUN when the user clicks on the plusquantity button-and this is exactly what is happening as you are seeing. IT DOES NOT run when the activity is launched. You should instead set the initial price within onCreate, but OUTSIDE of the setOnClickListener-that way it will set the price when the activity is launched.

Comment: @Shades That is OP's same question that I answered a month ago! LOL

Comment: @shagberg Yeah I saw that... Hopefully in the future they'll leave a comment to ask for clarification rather than post the question again, it just clogs up the site so much if a lot of people ask the same question multiple times.